# Існування слова "медальки"

Tags: запозичені-слова

Чи існує слово "медальки" в українській мові як самостійне слово, що притаманне саме нашому спілкуванню, а не є запозичиним русизмом слова "медальки" (мєдалькі)? Зі згадок та використань цього слова (згідно тлумачному словнику http://sum.in.ua/s/medaljka) є лише одна у творі М. Яновського, що за часом припадає саме на СРСР та його нав'язування всього *поганого*. Допоможіть, будь ласка.

Comment: **−1.** Просто цїкаво, пробували поглянути в гиншому словника чи, що був до СРРР? Но і ще, що думаєте про _медаль_ (як старе слово?) + _ка_ — чому це неможливо?

Comment: Звучить по-українськи.